# FLT_HAS_SUBNORM is 0: does manually constructed subnormal lead to well-defined behavior when using such subnormal?

Tags: c, ieee-754

In case if `FLT_HAS_SUBNORM` is 0: does manually constructed (using, for example, type punning via `union` or using `memcpy()`) subnormal lead to well-defined behavior when such subnormal is used as an input for FP operations (for example, FP comparison)?

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <float.h>
int main( void )
{
    union { unsigned int i; float f; } u = { .i = 1 }; // subnormal
    printf("%d %d %a 0x%08lx\n", FLT_HAS_SUBNORM, u.f != 0.0f, u.f, u.i);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

clang: `1 1 0x1p-149 0x00000001`

gcc: `1 1 0x1p-149 0x00000001`

test compiler: `0 1 0x0p+0 0x00000001`

Note: here we see that test compiler does not support `%a` for subnormals (which is explained by / correlates with `FLT_HAS_SUBNORM` is 0).

Questions:

1. Is `u.f != 0` here leads to well-defined behavior?
2. If so, then why C standard permits such manually constructed subnormals (as well as FP operations with such manually constructed subnormals leading to IEEE 754 conformant results) if `FLT_HAS_SUBNORM` is 0?

UPD. I've read the standard. I'm confused because it says:

> FLT_HAS_SUBNORM is 0 means that `subnormal numbers are absent (type does not support subnormal numbers)`

However, despite of `type does not support subnormal numbers` in the example above we've seen that it is possible to manually construct subnormals and perform some FP operations on them getting IEEE 754 conformant results.

UPD. In other words: shall the example above (`u.f != 0.0f`) be interpreted as a violation of `FLT_HAS_SUBNORM is 0`? If so, then please prove it.

Comment: I would think `FLT_HAS_SUBNORM` is about floating-point formats that *don't have a represenation for subnormal numbers at all*. If you can't create a bitpattern that represents a subnormal number, your question cannot ever be relevant. But I'm wrong about that: C11 draft standard n1570: *26) Characterization as absent is intended if no floating-point operations produce subnormal results from
non-subnormal inputs, even if the type format includes representations of subnormal numbers.*

Comment: pmor, Why do you think  `u.f` is a sub-normal?   `fabsf(u.f) < FLT_MIN  && u.f != 0` would be a better test.  Post its value with `"%a"`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Posted (both `%a` and `0x%08lx`).

Comment: Your output is consistent with a big endian system where an `int` is bigger than a `float`. You have not demonstrated the ability to *"manually construct subnormals"*. Nor have you demonstrated that you are able to *"perform some FP operations on them"*

Comment: It is possible that `u.f` value is simply invalid or not consistently interpreted.  So printing it or comparing to 0.0  is not sufficiently convincing as to its _value_.  Perhaps printing it as  `printf("%a\n", u.f  * powf(2, 100));` might print  `0x1p-49` or some nearby value and so we can deduce `u.f`.  In the end it simply looks UB as [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65296492/2410359).

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Confirm that gcc, clang and cl (msvc) produce .exe, which prints `0x1p-49`.

Comment: I suspect in your `cl`, the artificial subnormal is _maybe_ evaluated  for most math as the expected sub-normal value.  For printing though, the `double` to text may simply take any sub-normals and zeros (all have the  0  biased exponent) and print zero - taking advantage that  sub-normals  do not occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is u.f != 0 here leads to well-defined behavior?

No. If subnormal numbers are not supported, then they are not supported regardless of how they are obtained, whether by literals in source code, arithmetic, or manipulation of the bits that represent floating-point objects.

> If so, then why C standard permits such manually constructed subnormals…

C is a low-level language and allows direct access to the bytes that represent any object. You can also construct representations of integers that are invalid due to parity errors (on implementations that have such) and representations of `char` objects that are not in the defined character set. You can also tinker with the bytes of a `FILE` or a `struct tm` and produce objects with unsupported values. The fact you can manipulate the bytes does not mean any manipulation of the bytes results in a valid or supported value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you prove (referring to the standard, using `proof by contradiction`, other ways) that `no`? P.S. I also inclined to think that `no`, but cannot prove yet.

Comment: @pmor: C 2018 4 2: “… Undefined behavior is otherwise indicated in this document… by the omission of any explicit definition of behavior…”

Comment: At which moment exactly UB occurs? At the moment of `manual constriction` (type punning, memcpy(), reading from file, etc.) or at the moment of execution of FP operation, which takes such manually constricted `floating-point object(s)` as input?

Comment: Question about `Characterization as absent .. from non-subnormal inputs, ...`. By requiring `from non-subnormal inputs` what exactly the standard implies: the fact that `subnormal inputs do not exist in this 'absent' characterization` (and, hence, cannot be constructed via type punning, memcpy(), reading from file, etc.) or the fact that `subnormal inputs may exist, but in this case some FP operations may produce subnormal results` (deduction from 'absent' characterization)?

Comment: @pmor: Writing bytes into the memory of an object has defined behavior. Reading the value of an object whose bytes are not a representation of some value in the type of the object has undefined behavior.

Comment: @pmor: That footnote says that if an implementation has subnormal values in its `float` type but they are never produced by operations with normal operands, that implementation should define `FLT_HAS_SUBNORM` to be 0. That is in addition to the fact that implementations that do not have subnormal values in its `float` type should define `FLT_HAS_SUBNORM` to be 0. So, if `FLT_HAS_SUBNORM` is 0, you cannot deduce whether the implementation does not have subnormal values in its type or whether it does have them but they cannot be produced from normal operands.

Comment: Yes, all that the standard says is that `If FLT_HAS_SUBNORM is 0, then any_normal <op> any_normal never produces subnormal`, which is not sufficient to answer all the questions about `FLT_HAS_SUBNORM is 0`. Can you add to your answer that UB occurs exactly at the moment of execution of FP operation, which takes such manually constricted floating-point object(s) as input (and not at the moment of manual construction of such floating-point object(s))?