# FLT_HAS_SUBNORM is 0: what fpclassify(<subnormal>) shall return: FP_SUBNORMAL or FP_ZERO, or lead to UB?

Tags: c, floating-point, language-lawyer, c11, subnormal-numbers

Follow-up question for:

1. [FLT_HAS_SUBNORM is 0: does execution of fpclassify() with manually constructed subnormal lead to UB or lead to WDB returning FP_SUBNORMAL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66027897/flt-has-subnorm-is-0-does-execution-of-fpclassify-with-manually-constructed-s)
2. [If the presence of subnormal numbers is optional (HAS_SUBNORM), then why the presence of FP_SUBNORMAL is mandatory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66385668/if-the-presence-of-subnormal-numbers-is-optional-has-subnorm-then-why-the-pre)

Question: in case of `FLT_HAS_SUBNORM is 0` what `fpclassify(<subnormal>)` shall return: `FP_SUBNORMAL` or `FP_ZERO`, or lead to UB? Please, elaborate.

In other words: in case of `FLT_HAS_SUBNORM is 0` shall the implementation have DAZ (Denormals Are Zero) property? (For the details see comment by user @njuffa in the link #1.) If yes / no, then shall this property be applied to all the operations involving FP numbers (objects), or to some operations involving FP numbers (objects)?

UPD20210825: Answer from the committee:

> It is FP_ZERO.

Consequences:

1. In case of `FLT_HAS_SUBNORM is 0` shall the implementation have DAZ (Denormals Are Zero) property set to 1? Yes.
2. Shall DAZ=1 be applied to all the operations involving FP numbers (objects)? In progress...

Comment: As far as I can tell, it is not defined what the implementation should do in this case, therefore UB.

Comment: How is this a follow-up question? It's essentially asking the same as question 1.

Comment: @pmor: While I agree with Ian Abbott that the standard does not define what should happen, as a toolchain vendor for hardware with no support for subnormals, you can still define implementation-specific behavior for your toolchain. Based on design principle of "least surprise", I would recommend that in an environment where bit patterns representing a subnormal are treated as zero, `fpclassify` return `FP_ZERO` when presented with such a bit pattern. Similar issue with `nextafterf (0.0f, INFINITY)` when there is no subnormal support (standard doesn't say; I made it advance to smallest normal).

Comment: @IanAbbott See UPD20210825.